# Unable to translate month name in the mobile web for reputation tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, mobile-web, localization

I can't find the string to translate month name when viewing the [profile reputation tab](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217?tab=reputation) in mobile view:

> [image: month]

The issue was found more than two years ago: [Отсутствие перевода названия месяца на странице репутации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3812/176217), but still not fixed.